# How to keep window always on active workspace?

Tags: gnome, workspaces, vlc, window

I'm using VLC to play a music video.

I use a lot of workspaces and I would like to keep it open and pinned on top on the active workspace.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is, just press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, that will bring the window menu. You have an option there that says **Always on Top**.

You can get that menu by right clicking on the top of the window when it's not maximized.

If would like the window to always remain on the current active workspace hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> again and select **Always on Visible Workspace**.

Comment: How do I make GNOME remember that for the next session?

Comment: @StevenRoose https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401422/defaulting-to-or-persisting-always-on-visible-workspace